# Sticky Footer for Customer Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, css

I have a lightning component that is working as the footer in my customer community.

I have made it sticky in a way that it is always there. Meaning it will always show in the bottom of the screen.

What I want is if I have a page with long content it should show at the bottom of the page, at the end of the content. and if I have no content then it should show up at the end of the screen instead of in the middle of the screen.

This is the code which I have tried in the CSS Editor. :

```
.footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```